# SAP Enterprise messaging - Add new queues with listeners to existing queues on runtime

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk

I have a usecase around SAP Enterprise messaging(Consume BusinessEvents from S4HC) to make it multitenant. For this, the approach is by making One queue per tenant and a particular queue would be subscribed to multiple business events of that tenant.
Currently, I have achieved the functionality to make it work/listen only for 1 queue with the following code. Note that all the events are asynchronous or non blocking calls with a listener class implemented.

```
    @Bean
public Connection getSession(MessagingServiceJmsConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws JMSException, InterruptedException {
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    //connection.start();
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    Queue queue = session.createQueue(QUEUE_PREFIX + QUEUE);
    final MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
    messageConsumer.setMessageListener(new DefaultMessageListener());
    connection.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    return connection;

}
```

Approach is to create queues on subscription callbacks through service manager and to make the application listen to the new queue(add it to existing queues) without stopping/restarting the app.
How to get the connection factory session and add the new queues with the listener to make it dynamic using SpringBoot?
Can you help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't look like the [SAP Cloud SDK](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/). We checked twice and the mentioned classes are not found in our code. We had PoC support for Enterprise Messaging but deprecated it in favor of the planned release of the library for it by Cloud Application Programming model (CAP)

Check CAP's section on the [Event Handlers](https://cap.cloud.sap/docs/java/provisioning-api) in Java for more details. As far as I can see from the [feature overview table](https://cap.cloud.sap/docs/about/features#events--messaging) CAP doesn't yet have support for multitenancy with the Java library. Implementation for Node.js is complete in that sense.

In SDK we plan to provide some convenience on top of the CAPs implementation when it's finalized. Their implementation

I think you can approach CAP via their [support channels](https://cap.cloud.sap/docs/resources/).

Comment: Hi Artyom, Thanks for the reply. I have followed the github sample 'https://github.com/SAP-samples/enterprise-messaging-client-java-samples' in SAP Cloud SDK to integrate with SAP s4h cloud. Is this deprecated now?

Comment: Also, am not using CAP model to integrate EMS.  Currently, using version SAP Cloud SDK 3.31.0

Comment: Hi @ArunKumar, I checked the repo. It's a generic sample in Java for consuming messaging. I don't think it's deprecated, but that's not created by SDK. We used to have a type-safe client implementation also using JMS as a backend but then we deprecated it in favor of CAP's library. You can probably integrate the SDK with the approach from the repo, but if smth failing in between I believe the best way to go is creating a GitHub issue in that repository.

Comment: I would also encourage you to try a CAP library if multitenancy is not your main concern.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...Use case is to create a multitenant app. With respect to CAP, I have read/heard about the issues integrating EMS. Hence cannot take that path.  I have achieved the EMS integrating using SDK but works in a single tenant manner.

Comment: Did you use this example + SDK? I think you can use our abstractions for multitenancy, but we don't yet have any for the EMS event listeners. You can create a feature request [here](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-sdk/issues/new/choose) with a bit more details about your app. We'll see if there's a workaround or smth.

Comment: Yes...have used this example + SDK...will raise an issue request in the link provided